# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un input creado dinámicamente para guardarlo en la Base de datos?

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

espero me puedan orientar con este código.
El problema es que no sé cómo recuperar el input de un formulario dinámico para guardarlo en la base de datos mysql.
Pongo un input, ya que éste va a  ser dinámico; cuando yo le dé clic en el icono "glyphicon-plus" este me va a clonar otro input.

Atentos que estoy usando jquery.min.js dentro del head.

```
<div>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" role="form">
  <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" >Enviar</button>
</form>
</div>
```

El código javascript que hace clonar al input es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var maxField = 3; //Input fields increment limitation
            var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
            var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
            var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove field"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a></div>'; //New input field html 
            var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
            $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
                if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                    x++; //Increment field counter
                    $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); // Add field html
                }
            });
            $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
                x--; //Decrement field counter
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Ahora vuelvo a preguntarles, ¿cómo capturo el valor cuando tenga dos input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fijate que en `name` del `input` tienes unos corchetes (**field_name[ ]**) esto declaran el nombre del `input` como un array, esto quiere decir que en `PHP` la variable `$_GET['field_name']` (o `$_POST['field_name']` segun el método de envio) será un array que puedes recorrer con un `foreach` por ejemplo.

Ejemplo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>array form</title>
</head>
<body>


    <form action="#" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" name='Enviar' value="Enviar"/>
    </form>


    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['Enviar'])) {

        // recorremos el array
        foreach ($_GET['field_name'] as $key => $value) {
            echo 'La clave es '.$key.' y el valor es '.$value.'<br/>';
        }

    }
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```